# Compile error on "system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject"

Tags: silverlight-4.0, compiler-errors, wcf-data-services

I use WCF service in SilverLight project. But While I compile solution, I got the errors as below:

```
命名空间"System.Runtime.Serialization"中不存在类型或命名空间名称"IExtensibleDataObject"(是否缺少程序集引用？）
```

Sorry, I worked in Chinese, the translation is below(from Google):

```
Namespace "System.Runtime.Serialization" does not exist in the type or namespace name "IExtensibleDataObject" (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have checked, the `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` have been added into the project.
And the same project worked well on other person's compute. Just mine can not complie.

Somebody Help!

Answer (score 2):

Add the reference **System.Runtime.Serialization** in the project.

Answer (score 0):

try to:

1. clean solution and rebuild solution
2. restart visual studio
3. restart pc

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that all your `.cs` solution files have same namespace.
2. Check if you have `System.Runtime.Serialization` reference added to your project.

[image]

3. Include `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` directive to your project.